# Create menu with modules assigned to user profiles in PHP

Tags: php, user-controls

I used UserCake and it works fine, but now I need to connect created user accounts with modules (tables created in phpMyAdmin). 
Simple I need to create menu with modules I managed and assigned to user.

User 1 after login will see for example; module2, module4
next User 2 will see: module3, module4
User 3: module1, module4
...

Assign must be managed only by me as admin. User only will get username & password and his package of assigned modules.

I hope I explained it good :).

Comment: Well, that explanation is quite understandable. Welcome to StackOverflow.

But it would be nice to know, what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. You should ask specific questions here, where you can accept a precise answer, not something with many possible solutions.

Comment: I know, but I am in situation when I need more solutions... Maybe I just can't explain my problem with correct name. :/

Comment: Then a forum is probably a better place to ask for some guidance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could make another table based on sth like:

```
[TABLE] user-has-modules:
id | userid | moduleid
0  | 0      | 0
1  | 0      | 1
2  | 0      | 2
3  | 1      | 0
4  | 1      | 1
5  | 2      | 0
6  | 2      | 2

[TABLE] users:
id  | username | etc...
0   | 'blabla1'
1   | 'blabla2'
2   | 'blabla3'
3   | 'blabla4'
4   | 'blabla5'

[TABLE] modules:
id  | name
0   | 'module1'
1   | 'module2'
2   | 'module3'
3   | 'module4'
4   | 'module5'
```

And then for the given user add or remove a table row afterwards. Later on you can choose the user over SQL and give/load the modules for the menu.